# Android development - CurrentActivity and LatestActivity classes not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I ran the HelloWorld android app and now I moved on to making buttons and stuff like that. I am able to create the buttons in the layout xml and all that, but I ran into some confusion over Eclipse not recognizing my Intent declarations.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
addProblemButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
{  
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
      CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

The CurrentActivity and NextActivity classes do not seem to be recognized and Eclipse and it doesn't give me the option to automatically create the import statements for it.

What is the package that these classes are in? Is it an issue of some things not recognized? Or some package that needs to be installed/downloaded? Whats the best practice way to handle such a situation?

Also, do I need to add listeners if I already added the buttons to the layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `CurrentActivity` and `NextActivity` are just being used as example names for classes for launching an activity in whatever code snippet you were looking at.

CurrentActivity should be the name of whatever the Activity class is that you're launching the new activity from, and NextActivity would be the name of some new Activity class that you want to navigate to next.

Comment: aaaah, got it! So are these classes like new screen representations?

Comment: Yup! Each screen or single unit of action that the user would do is represented by an Activity. You use Intents to launch Activities.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems you are trying a tutorial. In your project, you should create your own classes extends `Activity`, named `CurrentActivity`and `NextActivity`, so Eclipse will know what they are.

2.If you just declare a button in the layout xml file, the app only show it, but doesn't know how to handle the click event on it, so you still have to register the listener for it. You can:

a.  Set the `android:onClick` attribute for the button in the layout file, and then implement the method to handle the click event. I.e. `android:onClick="click"` in the xml, and add a function with that name in your code:

```
    public void click(View v){
    //Process click event here
}
```

b. register the listener fully in code:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Process click event here
        }
    });
```